# How to use XPATH for Webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I'm learning so please excuse stupid questions.

I'm running the following but it returns no results, when I'd expect it to return a value from the web page I'm searching.

```
# Import required modules
from lxml import html
import requests
import time
  
# Request the page
page = requests.get("https://www.spirehealthcare.com/spire-cambridge-lea-hospital/treatments/prices/")

# Parsing the page
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# Get element using XPath HIP REPLACEMENT TREATMENT 

prices = tree.xpath(
    '//*[@id="pricingaccordionheader34807"]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]//text')   
prices

Output = []
```

Comment: Would you like to try using (BeautifulSoup)[https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/] (library for Web scraping)?

Comment: there is no element with that ID on that page, so its hard to say if your xpath is correct or not :/
update: oh, i see..i think the menu is lazy-loaded, which might explain why your snippet doesnt work

Comment: Thanks - i'll do some research into scraping lazy-loaded pages and see what i find

Answer (score 0):

When I go that page, I get as far as `//*[@id="pricingaccordionheader34807"]/div` and that contains:

```
<p><b>We can't display a fee for this procedure just now. Call us for a quote.</b></p>
```

Maybe you need to be logged in or something to see more/different content? Or it dynamically adds the prices when you click to expand (not the original content served in the initial HTML response).

But that's why it's not selecting and returning what you would expect. The content you are looking for doesn't exist there.

Comment: Thank you for your response.   How about this? prices = tree.xpath(
    '//*[@id="pricingaccordionheader34750"]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')   
prices   it's the same but different code, which i know to be there.

Comment: i think it's related to being an accordion type box related to a selected site which i'm not specifying in my query